# detect ACTION_MOVE on imageView using selector

Tags: android, android-view

I created xml file and use selector to make a button change its background.

it works perfectly ; on touch it changes background and when  finger exit view it returns to normal state ; what i want is that when the finger go back to the view it has to change its background again with the same color.
I did it by Code Java this is the code But i want to do same thing by using just xml file:

```
imgButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            cmp++;
            txt2.setText(" " + cmp);
            //when touch image :
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                imgButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
            // finger draging...
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                //... and finger exit image do this
                if (event.getX() < 0 || event.getX() > v.getWidth() || event.getY() < 0 || event.getY() > v.getHeight()) {
                    imgButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x00000001, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                }
                if (event.getX() > 0 && event.getX() < v.getWidth() && event.getY() > 0 && event.getY() < v.getHeight()) {
                    // ... and finger in the image do this
                    imgButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Selector :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="#00FF00"/>
    </item>
    <item android:="true">
        <color android:color="#000000"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Layout

```html
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/str"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgstart"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hhhh"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
```

Comment: and when your finger move to that button in device?. can you please elaborate ? because I dont think there is any event like howering in android. or are you trying to tell somthing else?

Comment: I did it with code java see my post i edited it , you can understand me more clearly with code than my bad english lool,  see my post i added code java